# Can a RegularExpressionValidator be overridden?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got 2 fields with RegularExpressionValidators:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClientID" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Height="18px" Width="80px" 
     Visible="False" Font-Size="Small" Wrap="False" OnTextChanged="txtClientID_OnLeave" 
     AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeClientID" runat="server" MaskType="Number" Mask="99999" 
     TargetControlID="txtClientID" PromptCharacter="_"  InputDirection="LeftToRight" 
     AutoComplete="False" UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtClientID" 
     ID="RevClientID" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{5,5}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="X" 
     ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Large"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="TBAccountNum" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Height="18px" Width="80px" 
     Font-Size="Small" AutoCompleteType="None" Visible="False" Wrap="False" 
     OnTextChanged="TBAccountNum_OnLeave" AutoPostBack ="true" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MeeAcctNum" runat="server" MaskType="Number" Mask="9999999" 
     TargetControlID="TBAccountNum" Enabled="False" 
     PromptCharacter="_" AutoComplete="False" InputDirection="LeftToRight"  />                                         
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="TBAccountNum" 
     ID="RevAcctNum" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{7,}$" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="7 Digits required." Enabled="False" ForeColor="White" 
     Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Now, what I'm being asked to do is allow the usr to enter either one or the other.  I should mention there are about 5 other fields on this page that have their own RegularExpressionValidators, but the user has decided that either one of the two fields above should be filled in.  Right now, it obviously gives an error if they're both empty.

Is there any way to override a RegularExpressionValidator to allow for either one or the other to be filled in?  If so, how could this be done?

Comment: A RegexValidator (like most validators) ignores empty textboxes - maybe that is enough for you? (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx), first note under Remarks)

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation!